# odeint error as "The size of the array returned by func (1) does not match the size of y0 (13)"

Tags: scipy, ode, odeint

I am getting an error when I am trying to solve a derivative by using scipy odeint function as "The size of the array returned by func (1) does not match the size of y0 (13)". Is there a way to find out the what is the size of the returned function?.

And is there a way to overcome this issue?.

Comment: Read the function code.  You can also do a test calculation using `y0`, time, and any args.  If you wrote the function you should be able test it!

Comment: Possibly argument order. It is (y,t) for odeint, (t,y) for all others, and odeint with option tfirst=True.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).